# How to call jar class

Tags: java

How to call JAR CLASS with CMD

I am a newcomer to java.

This is my JAR file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bL0n4KS9IP75tDJhhbeNLeiS3boX3iP/view?usp=sharing

I want to use CMD to call the CLASS inside JAR.

I tried to call getHardware()

java -cp uhfrcom13_v1.9.jar com.handheld.uhfr.UHFRManager.getHardware

I got the error

The main method is not found, define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) Otherwise the JavaFX application class must extend javafx. The application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Please master teach me how to call

Comment: _Please master teach me how to call_  -- who is the master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes and it will work.

1. Make sure to have a main method (public static void main (String [] args)) in your class where getHardware is a method, then call your getHardware method to work on from the main method [you should call the class from CMD and not the specific method!!].
2. Make sure to use the following command, in CMD, assuming your class is UHFRManager and getHardware is a method inside it,
   `java -cp "uhfrcom13_v1.9.jar" com.handheld.uhfr.UHFRManager` 
   I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

In `UHFRManager` class you have to add `public static void main(String[] args)` - in this method you can call your `getHardware()` method. When running jar file, java is always looking for `main` method in your class.